# How to scroll div content by using fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

My page code looks like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="panel">
    <div id="answerData">
      <div id="bodyData">
      ----some contents here ----
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The data got wrapped between bodyData are populated automatically, so I want to make these data scrollable when they are overflowed.
And I added

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#wrap').fullpage();
    })
</script>
```

below div section, but nothing happened, anyone can help me? I followed a tutorial video, don't know how to initialize fullpage.

Answer (score 0):

Check [the fullPage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) where everything is explained in detail and with [plenty of examples](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples).

You are not following the required HTML structure which is the following:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

You can also check [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6602KMtq1Y&t=203s).